# Wix + IIS : Creating a virtual directory on a web site with bindings for port 80 disabled

Tags: iis, wix, virtual-directory

I have a Wix installed which creates a virtual directory in IIS via the following:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLLOCATION">
  <Component Id="VirtualDirectory" Guid="29BEECCC-AA5F-11DF-BBB1-9C0AE0D72085">
    <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="MyVDir" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION" Alias="MyVDir" WebSite="DefaultWebSite">
      <iis:WebApplication Id="MyApplication" Name="MyVDir" />
    </iis:WebVirtualDir>
    <CreateFolder />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
<iis:WebSite Id="DefaultWebSite" Description="Default Web Site">
  <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="80" />
</iis:WebSite>
```

However this fails if the bindings for port 80 have been removed for that web site.

The `<iis:WebAddress />` element and `Port` attributes are both mandatory, however completely superfluous in this case - I don't care what the Port of the web site is, as long as it creates my virtual directory!

Is there any way of getting the above installer to successfully create a virtual directory without prompting the user for a port number?

Comment: Why do you think that port doesn't matter if you creates a virtual directory??! Virtual directory - where? On a site. What site? On port xyz

Comment: @abatishchev - Why **would** it matter? Once I've identified that I want to create the virtual directory on site with description "XYZ",  can either specify a port that exists for that site, in which case it works (and creates the virtual directory "for all ports"), or I specify one that doesn't exist, and it doesn't work - its essentially a very complicated "Fail while installing" boolean flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that as long as the `SiteId` attribute is provided the port is in fact ignored. The solution to my problem was to therefore change my `WebSite` element to be:

```
<iis:WebSite Id="DefaultWebSite" Description="Default Web Site" SiteId="*">
  <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="1" />
</iis:WebSite>
```

Note that the `Port` attribute is still required (and cannot be 0), however is ignored even if the `SiteId` attribute is `*` (meaning that the description is used to identify the site).

See [WebSite Element (WiX documentation)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_website.htm) for more information.

Comment: didn't work for me. Installer updated the bindings with http and port 1

Comment: UPDATE: I got it!!! The iis:WebSite must NOT be under component if you don't want to create site, per http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/iis/website.html : `Nesting WebSite under Product, Fragment, or Module results in a web site "locator" record being created in the IIsWebSite table. This means that the web site itself is neither installed nor uninstalled by the MSI package`

Answer (score 1):

All virtual directories are rooted in a web site. The WebSite element can be used to **create** a web site if WebSite element is under Component element or used to **find** a web site if not. The VirtualDir element must refer to a WebSite element somehow. That's the design of IIS thus the WiX models this way.

*Note: One might argue that WebSite element not under a Component element should have been named "WebSiteSearch" or something.*

Comment: I get that the VirtualDir element must refer to a WebSite element somehow, however why does the WebSite element need to explicitly specify a port even when using an existing site?

Comment: I have a number of sites on my IIS7 and most of them has virtual dirs and I didn't saw any mentions between root site and others

Comment: WebSite element has slowly morphed over time to allow different ways of finding the web site you want. Originally, the thinking is that the only guaranteed unique value for a web site was its port. Later we added the ability to find the web site by id and by description. Take a look at the documentation. The element is a bit more complex than it should be at this point because our understanding of IIS morphed over time... and IIS changed guidance from IIS5 to IIS6 to IIS7.